# AngularJS app should delay start after read file

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-cordova

My AngularJS app required to read stored settings before it started, but the problem is that the app starts before reading the file from the storege memory.
I am using "cordova.file.dataDirectory" inside "onDeviceReady" event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ng-strict-di](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) should do the job

In your index.html:

```
<body ng-controller="myAppController" ng-strict-di>
```

And in after you successfully read your file start up the app using [angular.bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)

```
angular.bootstrap(window.document.body, ['myApp']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use manual bootstrapping for this, add a custom code that waits and reads the directory and then start your angular app.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Instead of using ng-app, use:
`angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);`